# FDT installation standalon or Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, actionscript-3, jvm, fdt

I'm an old user of FDT and when it works is really nice. But I have to reinstall my system now and I do not success to install FDT.
When installing the stand alone version (4) I get Windows error 2 on loading JVM.
I have JRE 8 updating 51.

I try to insatall as plugin for Eclipse. I have tested at least five diferents versions of Eclipse. The result is always

> "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: FDT UI Extension (required)
>   4.5.3.1358 (com.powerflasher.fdt.ui.extension.feature.group 4.5.3.1358)   Missing requirement: FDT Core (required) 4.5.3.1358 (com.powerflasher.fdt.ui.feature.group 4.5.3.1358) requires
>   'org.eclipse.update.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found   Cannot
>   satisfy dependency:
>       From: FDT UI Extension (required) 4.5.3.1358 (com.powerflasher.fdt.ui.extension.feature.group 4.5.3.1358)
>       To: com.powerflasher.fdt.ui.feature.group [4.5.3.1358]"

I cannot find adocumentation with a clear solution. And of course I run all as admin.
Any suggestion?
Thanks